# Integrate SFML 2.5 RenderWindow into Qt 6 QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, sfml

In the [SFML 2.5 documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php) it is said:

> In case you really need advanced features for your window, you can
> create one (or even a full GUI) with another library, and embed SFML
> into it. To do so, you can use the other constructor, or create
> function, of sf::Window which takes the OS-specific handle of an
> existing window. In this case, SFML will create a drawing context
> inside the given window and catch all its events without interfering
> with the parent window management.
>
> ```
> sf::WindowHandle handle = /* specific to what you're doing and the library you're using */;
> sf::Window window(handle);
> ```

I want to embed SFML into my Qt GUI. Qt has a QOpenGLWidget class that I added to my project and into which I want to embed my SFML window (this should work since SFML is also based on OpenGL). But I have no idea how to do this. The only resource I could find on this topic was this: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-qt.php

But it refers to an old version of SFML.

Assuming I have a QMainWindow that has a QOpenGLWidget inside it, how would I embed an SFML window into it?

Comment: Have you tried using the code example from the old SFML tutorial -- it looks quite reasonable?  Note though, that using a `QOpenGLWidget` as the embedding target is probably *not* a good idea as it will have its own OpenGL context which may make things very awkward.

Comment: I tried to follow the example, but I had to do a substantial number of changes because it wouldn't compile as it is, also the code was incomplete so I had to add a lot of stuff to make it compile... but it doesn't work... only  black rectangle shows up. The X11 stuff also seems outdated.

Comment: Ok, I somehow got it working, I can draw stuff now, but it seems like events like mouse clicks and key board presses aren't generated... don't know how to make that work now...